# How to add a one second delay on mouseout

Tags: jquery, performance, animation

I assumed this would be simple but was wrong... tried using .delay and a combination of other methods found online but could not get it to work without bugs.

I just want to add a one second delay when you mouse off of .hover-area... any ideas??

Thanks in advance!!!

```
$('.forward').css({ opacity:0, right:-20 });
$('.backward').css({ opacity:0, left:-20 });

$('.hover-area').hover(function () {
  var conf_1 = { queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic' };
  var conf_2 = { queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic' };

  $(this).find('.backward, .forward').each(function () {
    $(this).stop()
      .animate($(this).data('animate-on'), conf_1)
      .animate({ opacity:0.7 }, conf_2);
  });
}, function() {
  var conf_1 = { queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine' };
  var conf_2 = { queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine' };

  $(this).find('.backward, .forward').each(function () {
    $(this).stop()
      .animate($(this).data('animate-off'), conf_1)
      .animate({ opacity:0 }, conf_2);
  });
});
```

Comment: have you tried .delay jQuery method.?

Comment: yes, but could not get it to work without issues.

Answer (score 0):

All seems fine just do a `.delay()` after `.stop()` in `your callback function` try with this:

```
$(this).find('.backward, .forward').each(function () {
$(this).stop().delay(1000)
  .animate($(this).data('animate-off'), conf_1)
  .animate({ opacity:0 }, conf_2);
});
```

What i have done here is just added a `.delay()` in you `mouseout` callback `function()`.

Comment: Can you add some explanation of what you are doing with this bit of code?

Comment: just `added a delay to the mouseout` function.

Comment: What I mean is for you to edit your answer and add the explanation... your answer showed up on the low quality review queue due to it being mainly a block of code. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do that by using `setTimeout`. Wrap your whole code inside a function which you want to execute on `mouseout` and put it with `setTimeout`.

Take a look on this sample or try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mvcGN/

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#test').hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","#456765");
    },function(){

//wrap your code in a function like this
        function do_it_after_delay(){
        $('#test').css('background-color','#567324');
        }


//simply use setTimeout to execute is with a delay
    setTimeout(do_it_after_delay,5000);

    });
});
```

This code will change the color of `#test` when your mouser enters the `DIV` and again change the color after 5 second your mouse left the `DIV`